# How to know exactly when the user scrolls to another carousel item on a carousel built with UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Im having a hard time trying to get notified and consequently run code whenever my horizontal carousel built with `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` changes to another cell / carousel item (aka the user scrolls to another carousel item). Upon googling, I found that I could do this with `UIScrollView` / `UICollectionView` delegate funcs such as `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, `scrollViewDidScroll`, etc. but turns out that these aren't called at all on horizontal `UICollectionViews` made with CompLayout.

Upon further googling, it turns out that there's a handler that can be set on the `NSCollectionLayoutSection`  that does seem to get called the minute the user starts scrolling ([visibleItemsInvalidationHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutsection/3199096-visibleitemsinvalidationhandler)). This closures gives me access to properties such as `items`, `contentOffset` and `environment`, though Im truly not sure how could I use these values to determine exactly the moment where the user changes to another cell. Im under the impression I need to do some manual calculations with the provided `contentOffset` the handler provides, but im quite lost honestly on what those calculations might be.
The `UICollectionView` is using a `.groupPaging` `orthogonalScrollingBehavior`

Any tip is super welcomed. Thanks!